# Robotium test method aren't recognised

Tags: android, testing, integration-testing, robotium

I'm new to Android testing and have never used Robotium before. When i add a new testing Method or change an old one, it doesn't get compiled. IntelliJ will always use the old one. Only solution is to restart IntelliJ. After the restart all the new Methods get recognised.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a Build -> Clean Project, Build -> Build Project?